# How do I find data from this day exactly one year ago?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Right now I have:

```
year(epe_curremploymentdate) = year(DATEADD(year, -1, SYSDATETIME()))
```

But that is giving me everything from last year.  All I want is the data from today's date, one year ago.

Comment: The way we have it, there is no leap year date starting point.  Thank you for that exception though

Comment: Don't forget to consider what you want (and what the DBMS provides) when the current date is a leap day (e.g. 2012-02-29).  You probably want and get 2011-02-28 as the 'exactly one year ago' date for both 2012-02-28 and 2012-02-29.  And, conversely, 2012-02-29 was never the 'exactly one year ago' date for any date in 2013. _(Resubmitted correcting typo of 2012-02-28 as the now corrected 2011-02-28.)_

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It should be:

```
epe_curremploymentdate = DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Don't check for **year** in your where clause.

**EDIT:**

Simple: use

```
cast(epe_curremploymentdate AS DATE) = cast(DATEADD(year, -1,
  GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```

That is, if you are using SQL Server 2008 and above.

Comment: The problem with this is: GETDATE returns minutes, seconds, etc. so it would only be an employee who started work last year at this exact time.

Comment: simple use cast(epe_curremploymentdate as date) = cast(DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()) as DATE), that is if you are using sql 2008, I have updated my answer

Comment: @user3630473 If this answer solved your issue, please mark this as answer (your profile is indicative of that). You never mark any answer. Please learn to mark answers as they will help other users in the future as well as showing gratitude to the people who took some time out of their life to help you out.

Comment: Now how would I look at 1 year plus two days? So if today is the 15th and I want to look at the 17th of last year?

Comment: @Doomsy just do (DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()) + 2)

Answer (score 5):

This should get you to where you need to go:

```
Declare @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime

-- @StartDate is midnight on today's date, last year
set @StartDate = Convert(date, (DATEADD(year, -1, getdate()))) 
set @EndDate = DATEADD(Day, 1, @StartDate)

select * 
from YourTable 
where epe_curremploymentdate >= @StartDate 
    and epe_curremploymentdate < @EndDate

-- This where clause will get you everything that happened at any time 
-- on today's date last year.
```

Comment: From where did you get the end date? It wasn't asked in the question and is not necessary. Only the start date part is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Date today:

```
select getdate()
```

date one year ago:

```
select dateadd(year, -1, getdate())
```

Date one year and one day ago:

```
select dateadd(d, -1 , dateadd(year, -1, getdate()))
```

**UPDATE**:

```
select *
from
epe_curremploymentdate = dateadd(year, -1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
```

This will give you a list of all employees who started working exactly from a year ago.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Could you explain the down vote or can you point me what is wrong in this answer?

Comment: what I am trying to find is all of the people that have started work exactly one year ago from today.

Comment: year(epe_curremploymentdate) = year (Dateadd(d, -1, DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())))

I'm still getting from all of last year (2013)

Comment: @user3630473 I've updated my answer. Take a look at it

Comment: I didn't downvote, but dateadd(d, -1 , dateadd(year, -1, getdate()))  gets the time -- so the exact day and time would have to match to be found.  This isn't what the asker is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you have other fields that show as datetime with the time part as 00:00:00.000, to do joins you can use the below

```
 dateadd(yy,-1,datediff(d,0,getdate()))
```

Answer (score 1):

epe_curremploymentdate = DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())